# Jquery - $(selector).scroll is passing parameters to its callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

i was reading those few lines of code from a javascript(Jquery) file and I was wondering where those arguments "x" and "y" are coming from.Is the scroll event that is taking care peraphs?

```
$(window).scroll(function(x,y) {

        dosomething(withThis);
    });
```

thanks
Luca

P.S. here is the jquery excerpt that made me ask this question  [Is this an elegant way to make elements fade in while scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160493/is-this-an-elegant-way-to-make-elements-fade-in-while-scrolling)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, open Firebug console (or web dev. tools) and paste there this code:

```
 $(window).scroll(function(x,y,z) {
    console.log(x,y,z)
 });
```

After execution and scrolling you'll see the result (works on sites with jQuery).

As expected, first argument - event object, 2nd and 3rd - undefined;

But, you can trigger events manually, and pass any arguments.

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: the console prints out exactly what you told me: Object {originalEvent=Event scroll, type="scroll", ...},undefined;

Comment: I just updated my question with a link .Could you please help me understand the meaning of those arguments? Or is just a syntax error?

Comment: Just an error, they aren't used in that script. But again - there are some use cases when you got to pass additional data (arguments) to the event handler.

Answer (score 2):

No, the handler for the [scroll event](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) takes only an event object, not `x,y`. That code is misleading and wrong. We can't help if you don't show the full code.

This is the same thing as if you define a method

```
function add(a,b) {
   return a + b;
}

// When called like this, b will be undefined, as is y in your example
// programmer error not caught by the compiler
add(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could inspect the `arguments` variable on any function, so you can get an idea of the data that's passed in.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

Comment: It's a good learning tool, but you should program from the interface (documentation) not from a specific usage, functions can get called from multiple contexts with different parameters

Comment: Absolutely, that's why I said it's just to get an idea of the data.